# Fixed div on left of container, full height of container (but not of page) using CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I want the following layout in my page:

[image: page layout]

The header and footer are always visible. The gray area is an `article` tag. The green and dark red areas are both inside a `nav` tag. The dark red has a fixed width, and is going to be used as a handle to resize the green navigation panel (it will be very narrow, of course, and I'll use JavaScript for the resizing). Both the gray and green areas must have their own scrollbars.

That's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>CSS template</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Header</header>
<main>
<nav>
    <div class='navcont'>
        <p>nav1</p>
        <p>nav2 with longer line just to make sure if everything is working as intended</p>
    </div>
    <div class='handle'>Handle</div>
</nav>
<article>
    <p>Article</p>
</article>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
header {
    text-align:center;
}
main {
    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    min-height:0;
}
article {
    background:#C0C0C0;
    width:80%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
nav {
    width:20%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.navcont {
    background:#00FF00;
    width:auto;
}
.handle {
    background:#800000;
    float:right;
    width:30px;
}
footer {
    text-align:center;
}
```

And a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/etwphhc8/

I tried many different solutions, from many different questions/answers here, but still haven't make it work as intended. So, how can I achieve the wanted layout using CSS?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/etwphhc8/2/

Comment: Yes, @MichaelCoker, of course! That's what we get for copying solutions, instead of thoroughly learning CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flex with the direction set to row in nav:

```
nav {
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: The flex-direction doesn't seem necessary. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot that flex-direction is row by default.  I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write:

```
  .navcont {
      background:#00FF00;
      width:auto;
      height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but then the footer disappeared from the page.